# Can not update the child component when passing with Input() decorator

Tags: angular, ngrx

I don't know why it displays this error when I try to update the value of pattern in app-check-pattern component

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'example' of object '[object Object]'
    at Object.handleEvent
```

This is how I call the component

```
<app-check-pattern [pattern]="(pattern$ | async)"
                         (eventPattern)="receiveAction($event)"></app-check-pattern>
```

And in the caller component I have this code

```
    export class PatternUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
      pattern$ : Observable<PatternModel>
      .......          
      constructor(public state : Store<AppSateWithPattern>) {
        this.state.replaceReducer(appReducerPatternDetailsUpdate)
        this.pattern$ = this.state.select((state:AppSateWithPatternDetails) => state.patternSelected);
        ..................
      }
.....
```

The cause is in pattern$ observable because I change with simple variable and it works
Any ideas how to fix this?

Update

```
 export interface PatternModel {
     .....
      pattern: string;
      transformation: string;
      example: string;
............

    }
```

Comment: Why not access the pattern$ without async. I don't know why the error am also curious

Comment: I pass the observable rather than the variable?

Comment: Yes and subscribe to the observable inside `app-check-pattern` or use async there .

Comment: pls show `PatternModel` class

Comment: @Skeptor : same error, beside I want to keep the Presentational and Container Components logic in my app

Comment: @n00dl3 : updated

Comment: Where does that data come from ? does it come from a library or is it crafted by yourself ? The error is pretty self-explainatory: `example` is readonly (it's just a getter, not a real property).

Comment: the data is in the observable variable pattern$ I have printed the value of pattern and everything seems okay but it's readonly and I don't know why! (The data is in the ngrx store)

Comment: hmmm if you are using ngrx, data is immutable... you need to use reducers to alter data...

Comment: This is what I did now ! I have use the cloneDeep of lodash library to get a new copy of the observable value and it works Thanks :)